# Conditions for uploading IEEE publications to ArXiv

Tags: publications, arxiv

Having a paper accepted at an IEEE conference I would like to upload it to ArXiv. From the [FAQ](http://www.ieee.org/documents/author_faq.pdf):

> Can an author post his manuscript on a preprint server such as ArXiv?
>   Yes. The IEEE recognizes that many authors share their unpublished
>   manuscripts on public sites. Once manuscripts have been accepted for
>   publication by IEEE, an author is required to post an IEEE copyright
>   notice on his preprint. Upon publication, the author must replace the
>   preprint with either 1) the full citation to the IEEE work with
>   Digital Object Identifiers (DOI) or a link to the paper’s abstract in
>   IEEE Xplore, or 2) the accepted version only (not the IEEEpublished
>   version), including the IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with
>   a link to the final, published paper in IEEE Xplore.

I am not quite sure what this exactly means. I have the latex source for the document I submitted to the conference. What modifications do I have to make in detail?

Do I have to add an extra page with "IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with a link to the final, published paper in IEEE Xplore". Where can I find the IEEE copyright notice?

I suppose I am not allowed to change any of the content, but what about the template? Do I have to use the format I submitted to the conference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add appropriate header/footer information about the copyright. If you have used the IEEEtran LaTeX package to prepare your paper, then [there is a standard means of doing so detailed in this TeX.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154503/72771).

Comment: I have submitted one to IEEE, but I have not yet received any feedbacks(its been more than a months now). Can I submit the same paper on arXiv now? with the IEEE template?

Comment: According to the IEEE statement above, yes, you can.  You may need to update it in the future based on the outcome of review, of course.

Comment: @jakebeal This might be related to this answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/172865/ieee-conference-chair-asked-to-take-down-arxiv-version-of-the-paper-within-24-ho

Comment: @MichelGokanKhan I added an answer there. Sounds like the conference chair doesn't understand arXiv and/or CrossCheck.

Answer (score 3):

Once accepted, you will get proofs (and later the final version) of the paper that contain these copyright notices etc. This is what you will need to upload. Just wait, and you will see :-)

Comment: Typically there is not a proof stage for conference papers.

Comment: I did receive nothing but had to validate my pdf via IEEE PDF eXpress and sent it to them.

Comment: For a journal article, IEEE gives a PDF for this purpose. (Actually, it is now also stated in the [FAQ](http://www.ieee.org/documents/author_version_faq.pdf): _"IEEE journals will make available to each author the accepted version of the article that the author can post that includes the DOI, IEEE copyright notice, and a notice indicating the article has been accepted for publication by IEEE."_) However, arXiv policy does not allow uploading the PDF version (I even emailed help@arxiv.org for this specific purpose), and IEEE does not give the source file (I asked them also).

Comment: If possible, change the Metadata of the article to point to the correct DOI of the published paper.  *Upon acceptance, previously posted versions must be replaced by a full
citation with DOI or the accepted version with DOI. Authors may share
or post their accepted article:* http://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/IEEE-Article-Sharing-and-Posting-Policies.pdf

Comment: @JiK, what did you end up doing for your article? Did you try to just bypass arXiv's policy that only allows uploading source files for LaTeX-based PDFs? Or did you manage to get the source files with IEEE?

Comment: @rafaelfp Doing some email acrheology, it seems that arXiv confirmed they need the source, and after some back&forth IEEE support said that they don't have any other source than the one I had prepared, (without the DOI&IEEE copyright notice that would be needed). It seems that the IEEE support didn't really understand the problem. So the only alternative would have been to add them to the source myself, and I ended up not updating the article in arXiv.

Answer (score 0):

According to [IEEE FAQ](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/author_version_faq.pdf):

> Once articles have been accepted for publication by IEEE, authors are required to post an IEEE copyright notice on their preprints. Upon publication, authors must replace the preprints with either 1) the full citation to the IEEE works with Digital Object Identifiers (DOI) or 2) the accepted versions only (not the IEEE-published versions) with the DOI